# How to determine why a query acquire a lock in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, deadlock

I've got some weird issue with Odoo and postgresql. It happens when I try to install the forum module on odoo 15. It's not that relevant and I'm not sure it's repeatable but if you can reproduce the bug that would be how.

Using the answers from this question: [How to detect query which holds the lock in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489244/how-to-detect-query-which-holds-the-lock-in-postgres)

I can find that the SQL query acquiring a lock is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ir_translation
          WHERE lang='en_US' AND
                type='model_terms' AND
                name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND
                res_id IN (2618)
```

The res_id (2618) is being created within the same transaction. But this query returns nothing because there is apparently no translation loaded yet.

```
                                  Table "public.ir_translation"
  Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   
----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 id       | integer           |           | not null | nextval('ir_translation_id_seq'::regclass)
 name     | character varying |           | not null | 
 res_id   | integer           |           |          | 
 lang     | character varying |           |          | 
 type     | character varying |           |          | 
 src      | text              |           |          | 
 value    | text              |           |          | 
 module   | character varying |           |          | 
 state    | character varying |           |          | 
 comments | text              |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "ir_translation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ir_translation_code_unique" UNIQUE, btree (type, lang, md5(src)) WHERE type::text = 'code'::text
    "ir_translation_comments_index" btree (comments)
    "ir_translation_model_unique" UNIQUE, btree (type, lang, name, res_id) WHERE type::text = 'model'::text
    "ir_translation_module_index" btree (module)
    "ir_translation_res_id_index" btree (res_id)
    "ir_translation_src_md5" btree (md5(src))
    "ir_translation_type_index" btree (type)
    "ir_translation_unique" UNIQUE, btree (type, name, lang, res_id, md5(src))
Foreign-key constraints:
    "ir_translation_lang_fkey_res_lang" FOREIGN KEY (lang) REFERENCES res_lang(code)
```

That's the schema for `ir_translation`.

Then there are 3 queries working from querying fields from `res_groups_users_rel, ir_model_data, ir_model_access, ir_model, ir_rule, rule_group_rel`. None of those query gets blocked.

After that there is this query that get stuck on a lock on the query with `ir_translation`.

```
SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."google_maps_api_key" as "google_maps_api_key", "website"."user_id" as "user_id", "website"."cdn_activated" as "cdn_activated", "website"."cdn_url" as "cdn_url", "website"."cdn_filters" as "cdn_filters", "website"."homepage_id" as "homepage_id", "website"."custom_code_head" as "custom_code_head", "website"."custom_code_footer" as "custom_code_footer", "website"."robots_txt" as "robots_txt", "website"."theme_id" as "theme_id", "website"."specific_user_account" as "specific_user_account", "website"."auth_signup_uninvited" as "auth_signup_uninvited", "website"."create_uid" as "create_uid", "website"."create_date" as "create_date", "website"."write_uid" as "write_uid", "website"."write_date" as "write_date", "website"."channel_id" as "channel_id", "website"."karma_profile_min" as "karma_profile_min" FROM "website" WHERE "website".id IN (1)
```

I don't really understand why a query on a website table with no direct ling to ir_translation can get locked.

Here's the result from `select * from lock_monitor;` view created based on the linked question.

```
 locked_item | waiting_duration | blocked_pid |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          blocked_query                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |  blocked_mode   | blocking_pid |                                                  blocking_query                                                   |      blocking_mode       
-------------+------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| AccessShareLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| RowShareLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| RowExclusiveLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| ShareRowExclusiveLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
 website     | 00:01:20.267783  |       21038 | SELECT "website"."id" as "id", "website"."name" as "name", "website"."sequence" as "sequence", "website"."domain" as "domain", "website"."company_id" as "company_id", "website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id", "website"."auto_redirect_lang" as "auto_redirect_lang", "website"."cookies_bar" as "cookies_bar", "website"."configurator_done" as "configurator_done", "website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter", "website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook", "website"."social_github" as "social_github", "website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin", "website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube", "website"."social_instagram" as "social_instagram", "website"."has_social_default_image" as "has_social_default_image", "website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key", "website"."google_management_client_id" as "google_management_client_id", "website"."google_management_client_secret" as "google_management_client_secret", "website"."google_search_console" as "google_search_console", "website"."goo | AccessShareLock |        21059 |  SELECT * FROM ir_translation                                                                                    +| AccessExclusiveLock
             |                  |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                 |              |                     WHERE lang='en_US' AND type='model_terms' AND name='ir.ui.view,arch_db' AND res_id IN (2619)  | 
(6 rows)
```

Technically everything is executed in the same transaction. So I'm not so certain why it is locking on a query it previously made. It would make sense if there were 2 concurrent transaction because the concurrency mode is set to serial but in this case I just don't see how 2 unrelated table can cause a lock.

But the PID seems to imply there are 2 processes and I can see two processes in top. Is it possible for postgres to create multiple process for 1 cursor?

Comment: Why do you think there should only be one process?  PostgreSQL is a multiuser system.  Unless you have taken steps to assure otherwise, you should always assume there are other connections.  Other people, other app servers, other people using the same app server, or another tty session you have running and then forgot about.

Comment: @jjanes because I'm the only user and spawning 1 single process. But I found the issue, during the update process of Odoo it would create a new cursor without releasing the previous one that kept a lock on some rows. There were really 2 cursors.